# node.js cannot find module sqlite - wrong version?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

With a fresh install of node, installing a site finishes without errors, but running server.js fails with:

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\xxx\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v14-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

Looking in that folder's parent, I see it has a subfolder node-v11-win32-x64

So do I need to update my sqlite separately from node?

PS - the entry in package.json for sqlite is: "sqlite3": "^3.0.2",

Comment: Did you run `npm install`? `sqlite3` isn't built into node.

Comment: I did.  Do I maybe need to uninstall my previous sqlite?

Comment: Have you found out how to fix it?

Comment: The latest version of sqlite3 is the 3.1.8. You should try to change your package.json. Maybe the problem was resolved

Comment: Have you tried `npm rebuild` ?